# Opportunity is nowhere

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opportunity

Is there any reason to keep this super generic tag around?

I would like to see it no where, not now here.

Comment: Fully agreed. I think we should really get around to cleaning up our tag categorization in general at some point, to focus around specific themes and issues to get better "similar question" links and the like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just untagged the last two questions. No one seems to have objected or downvoted and there were only a few questions anyways.